# Windows 8.1 does not shown up on Grub2, even after installing Boot Repair. - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, windows-8, boot-repair

This is my first time installing Ubuntu 16.04. I have Windows 8 on my PC, and I downloaded Ubuntu 16.04, put it on a DVD then installed it on my PC.

When I turned on my PC after installing Ubuntu 16.04, no GNU Grub appeared. No option to choose Ubuntu or Windows. It directly booted-up Ubuntu 16.04.

I searched for an answer. I followed suggestion by installing Boot Repair.

> > > open a new Terminal, then type:
> > >       sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
> > >           Press Enter
> > >           Then type:
> > >       sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
> > >           Press Enter

Now, GNU Grub shown up. But no option for Windows. It's just:

> Ubuntu
>   Advance Options for Ubuntu

Now I do not know what to do. I need to work and access my document on windows 8.

Comment: Is this a newish computer ? If so, look in the BIOS / set-up program for any boot order option where you can select windows 8, or possibly an option to enable "legacy" boot or something like that, and toggle it. Did you change any settings there prior to installing Ubuntu ? I had a very similar problem with a friend's Lenovo.

Comment: try doing `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` & `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Your earlier problem could have been solved without boot-repair, Just by setting `Grub-Timeout` to a non-zero value (If that was the cause)

Comment: Rather than guess what your configuration is, post the link to the Summary Report from Boot-Repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info Report will also show if you installed in BIOS/CSM or UEFI boot mode. But you have to know if system is Booting with UEFI or BIOS settings in UEFI.

Comment: I followed suggestion by cl-netbox to check first if  i wrongly choose the option when i installed ubuntu (choosed the option to use whole disk for ubuntu). I have checked using 'Disks' and found out that there is no Windows anymore.... Thank you all for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you accidentally have chosen the option the use the whole disk for Ubuntu when you started the installer. In this case the whole disk was wiped and Windows with all data is gone. There is a slightly chance that this did not happen and something went wrong when it came to the configuration of the GRUB boot loader. Open a terminal in Ubuntu, execute this command : `sudo update-grub`. Reboot and check whether you find the Windows entry in the boot menu.

Additionally you can check the content of the disk with the `Disks` application, which is included in Ubuntu. Open `Disks` and check whether you can see more partitions than `Linux` and `Swap`. If this is the case reinstall the boot loader : `sudo grub-install /dev/sd*`, replace `*` with the drive letter of the disk where the systems are installed, in most cases this is the first disk `sda`. Afterwards update the GRUB configuration as it was described before : `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I've checked with the Disks, and there is no more Windows... I thought that LVM is the option for dual OS. Thank you cl-netbox. Now i need to reinstall windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off boot repair. Reboot to save changes. Then once you reach the login screen, shutdown. Turn on the computer, and hold down the shift key while it boots up. You will be greeted by the grub menu:

[image]

Windows 8.1 should be a boot option in the grub menu. If it is one of the options available, select Windows 8.1. That's it, you should be able to boot into Windows 8.1 via the grub menu.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Simply restart your OS. When it boots up hold down the shift key (or down-arrow), if you hit enter on `Advance Option for Ubuntu` you will still get the grub menu, here go to `(recovery mode)`

There you are supposed to get an option to repair/recover grub menu.
You can try by selecting each options got there by restarting again.

Hope it helps to resolve your issues.

Comment: I followed suggestion by cl-netbox to check first if  i wrongly choose the option when i installed ubuntu (choosed the option to use whole disk for ubuntu). I have checked using 'Disks' and found out that there is no Windows anymore.... Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: You are most welcome! :-)
With Regards.